# c# adding random numbers to array

Tags: c#

I am making a array filled with random numbers in c# but I can't get it to work.

```
        int[,] array = new int[10, 5];
        int x, y;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;

        while (y <= 5)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int rand = r.Next(-50, 50);
            array[x, y] = rand;

            if (x == 10)
            {
                x = 0;
                y++;
            }
            x++;

        }
```

Comment: Take `Random r = new Random();` out of the while loop. Otherwise, you're reseeding with the same seed every time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use nested `for` loops, it is much easier:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        array[i, j] = rnd.Next(-50, 50);
    }
}
```

Your `while` loop is not readable but it's correct,except you should change while `(y <= 5)` to `while (y < 5)` otherwise you will get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. And you should define your `Random` instance outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[,] array = new int[10, 5];
int x = 0, y = 0;

Random r = new Random();
while (y < 5)
{    
    int rand = r.Next(-50, 50);
    array [x, y] = rand;

    x++;
    if (x == 10)
    {
        x = 0;
        y++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change yours if or array declaration to

```
 int[,] array = new int[11, 6];
```

also there is other problem, you need to create random before while

```
        Random r = new Random();

        while (y <= 5)
        {
```

to print out the values you can use for

```
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
                Console.WriteLine(array[i, j]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[,] array = new int[10, 5];


        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
            {
                array[row, col] = rnd.Next(-50, 50);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[,] array = new int[10, 5];
        int x, y;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;

        while (y < 5)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int rand = r.Next(-50, 50);
            array[x, y] = rand;

            if (x == 9)
            {
                x = 0;
                y++;
            }
            x++;

        }
```

Let's see if this works.